# Magento 2 Plugin Not Being called or var_dump/die not showing?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, plugin

I created a module with a basic configuration option. I want to create a plugin that will act once that option is saved, but i can not tell if the plugin is not being called or my die(var_dump()) does not work on plugin code. 
Here is what i have:

app/code/Pera/CustomerFreeShipping/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Magento_Config::before" type="Pera\CustomerFreeShipping\Model\ConfigPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="true" />
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Pera/CustomerFreeShipping/Model/ConfigPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Pera\CustomerFreeShipping\Model;

class ConfigPlugin {

    public function beforeSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject)
    {
        die(var_dump($subject));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change config. Your plugin is disabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Magento_Config::before" type="Pera\CustomerFreeShipping\Model\ConfigPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

And plugin [Pera/CustomerFreeShipping/Model/ConfigPlugin.php]

```
namespace Pera\CustomerFreeShipping\Model;

class ConfigPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $log;

    /**
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $log
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $log
    ) {
        $this->log = $log;
    }

    public function beforeSave(
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config $subject
    ){
        $this->log->error('ConfigPlugin');
    }
}
```

Clear cache

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the disabled element as false in di.xml.

```
    <plugin name="Magento_Config::before" type="Pera\CustomerFreeShipping\Model\ConfigPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
```

> To disable a plugin, set this element to true. The default value is
>   false.

Remove the cache and check.

For more details please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html